# Powershell IE Automation FireEvent not triggering

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-9

So here is my dilemma. This is a part of the code:

```
$ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl11_SSLControl_ddlIndustry").SelectedIndex = "6"
$ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl11_SSLControl_ddlIndustry").FireEvent("onchange")
```

When I run this as part of a script the FireEvent doesn't trigger. I get the return value True, but the action does not work. If I copy and paste each line in Powershell manually, the FireEvent works.

What I think is that Powershell is not waiting for the firevent to finish triggering and is already going to the next line.

My question, how can I tell powershell to wait for the entire command to finish or some other alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are different types of [Browser Waits](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html). Which one do you need? [Checking the browser is busy](http://www.westerndevs.com/simple-powershell-automation-browser-based-tasks/)?

Answer (score 2):

[Dave White's Solution](http://www.westerndevs.com/simple-powershell-automation-browser-based-tasks/) is to add a wait while the browser is busy

```
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
```

Comment: The issue here is not with the browser not waiting it's with powershell, it runs the line that has the FireEvent, and then goes immediately to the next line.
My question here is how do I tell powershell to wait for that command to finish, before going to the next line of script.

Comment: Although this did help me on another part of the script! Thanks!